# How do I get all Access check list while accessing a page?

Tags: views, 8, users

How do I get all Access check while accessing a page?

Example: If I am accessing http://www.example.com then how many "permission check/access check" is executing.

Like: For viewing all available blocks, Nodes, links etc.

Comment: Do you want to enable all blocks/views etc on a page?

Comment: No, Some blocks are already enabled on the <front> page. Just want to know how many "Access check/ Permission check"is executing if I am accessing a page which contains some left ,right and content region blocks.